# Regex Expression for word with certain unrepeated characters

Tags: php, regex

So I can't figure out how I would write a regex expression for finding words with certain letters in them that don't repeat.

So if lets say I want words with the letters "elolh"

Then these would match:
hello
hell
lol

But this wouldnt:
eel (because e repeats twice but there's only 1 e in my letters provided.

Comment: it's not about regex, it's more about "count values"

Comment: I need it as a regex expression though

Comment: *I need it* is an off-topic issue. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: so I've tried  /\b[elolh]+\b/ but this returns eel for me as well

Comment: Of course `/\b[elolh]+\b/` does return `eel` since it means 1 or more characters in the set defined. Did you check it at regex101.com? Now, if you need to count the characters, a regex can be used, but it should be built dynamically since you need to introduce the lookahead checks with limiting quantifiers.

Comment: kind of confused what you mean by that, how would I go about doing that

Comment: The point is, you'll need to use PHP code to build a new regex for every template string (i.e, `elolh`), and the regexes it produces will be hideous.  It will be much simpler to write a function to do the job using basic string manipulation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The "rigid" and "simple" solution using `array_count_values`, `array_walk`, `str_split` and `array_intersect_assoc` functions:

```
$pattern = "elolh";
$input = "hello eel lol heel ello";

function findValidWords($pattern, $input) {
    $frequencies = array_count_values(str_split($pattern, 1));

    $words = explode(" ", $input);
    /**
     * will compare character occurrence indices between the main "pattern"
     * and each word from the input string
    */
    array_walk($words, function(&$v) use($frequencies){
        $counts = array_count_values(str_split($v, 1));
        $compared = array_intersect_assoc($counts, $frequencies);
        if (count($counts) != count($compared)) $v = "";
    });

    return array_filter($words);
}

$valid_words = findValidWords($pattern, $input);
print_r($valid_words);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [2] => lol
    [4] => ello
)
```